# first and last row_number

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table with many different companies, each with a number of orders ranging from only 1 to a possible n

I have used

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CompanyName ORDER BY OrderDate) AS Orders
```

This gives me a sample like below

```
Comp1   1
Comp2   1
Comp3   1
Comp3   2
Comp3   3
Comp3   4
Comp4   1
Comp4   2
Comp4   3
```

How do I go through the table and select the first and last record for each company? to end up with:

```
Comp1   1
Comp2   1
Comp3   1
Comp3   4
Comp4   1
Comp4   3
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `row_number()` twice or `count()`:

```
select c.*
from (select c.*,
             row_number() over (partition by CompanyName order by OrderDate) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by CompanyName) as cnt
      from companies c
     ) c
where seqnum = 1 or seqnum = cnt;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from Orders
where (CompanyName , OrderDate) in (
    select CompanyName , min(OrderDate) from Orders group by CompanyName 
    union all
    select CompanyName , max(OrderDate) from Orders group by CompanyName 
)
```